# Send login data to server using AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, server, android-volley

I am trying to send some data(login data - phonenumber, password) to the server using the Volley library. 
The tool is AndroidStudio.

```
private void checkLogin(final String phonenumber, final String password){


    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public synchronized void onResponse(String response){

            Log.d(TAG, "login_response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try{
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                //check for error node in json
                if(!error){
                    //user successfully logged in
                    //create login session

                    session.setLogin(true);

                    //launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
                else{
                    //error in login. get the error message
                   String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                //JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public synchronized void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            Log.e(TAG, "login_error: "+error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){

            //posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("phonenumber", phonenumber);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };

    //adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}

private void showDialog(){
    if(!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog(){
    if(pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Unfortunately no json is sent to server. 
Here is the code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To send Json with request you have to use **'JsonObjectRequest'**:

```
JsonObjectRequest registrationRequest = new JsonObjectRequest('Your URL', "your json object",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(registrationRequest);
```

Hope It will help.!!

Comment: Is it safe to send login (email/password) to server using json?

Comment: @GNIUS : Yes.It is safe.though i would suggest you to send encoded username and password to server and decode there for secure applications..!!